# Google is indexing my site as HTTPS and HTTP

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, search-engine-indexing, meta-description

I went to search my site to see how Google is indexing it and it is for some reason all jacked up.

I am seeing some pages indexed as HTTPS and then the same pages as not. Also the meta description is jacked up on some of them but correct on others.

I have no clue why this is happening. Any tips?

Comment: Have you verified your site with Google Search Console?   Do you use canonical tags?  Do you have an XML site map?

Comment: Also consider having HTTP redirected to HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

this happens, because of missed redirection from http to https: pages are available with both protocols. Create search console properties for both kinds, and then redirect all http urls to https, with something like, in PHP

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != 443) {
$redir = "Location: https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
header($redir);
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
exit();
}
?>
```

or, for Apache

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>
```